# How to align Entity to 3 separate anchors in RealityKit/ARkit?

Tags: ios, swift, alignment, arkit, realitykit

I am developing an app using ARKit and RealityKit.

I want to put a virtual box in the scene and align it with the physical object in three planes(x,y,z)

I was able to place the box in the scene (on floor).

[image]

The box is already aligned to the z-axis
I think after placing the box you should have chosen the planes to align to.

1. first touch on the x-axis plane of the physical object
2. second touch on the z-axis plane of the physical object

Below is the code I use

```
var box: ModelEntity!
var numberOfTouches: Int = 0

@objc func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        
        print("tap")

        let point:CGPoint = sender.location(in: nil)
        
        guard let queryFirst = self.sceneView.makeRaycastQuery(
            from: point,
            allowing: .existingPlaneInfinite,//.estimatedPlane,
            alignment: self.box == nil ? .horizontal : .vertical
        )
        else { return }

        let result = self.sceneView.session.raycast(queryFirst)

        guard let raycastResult = result.first
        else { return }
        
        let anchor = AnchorEntity(raycastResult: raycastResult)

        //If there is no box, then put it in the scene
        if(self.box == nil){
          var material = SimpleMaterial()

          material.tintColor = UIColor.init(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1)
          material.baseColor = MaterialColorParameter.color(UIColor.white)
        
          self.box = ModelEntity(
            mesh: MeshResource.generateBox(size: 0.25),
            materials: [material]
          )

          //is already aligned to the z-axis
        
          anchor.addChild(self.box)
          sceneView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
        }else{
          
          //If there is a box in the scene, then align to the current anchor:
          //1) first touch on plane of the physical object - align on the x-axis
          //2) second touch on the other plane of the physical object - align on the z-axis

          numberOfTouches += 1

          if(numberOfTouches == 1){
            // How align self.box on x-axis anchor ?
          }
          
          if(numberOfTouches == 2){
            // How align self.box on y-axis anchor ?
          }
          
        }
}
```

How do I align to the other axes?
And for the box to fit into the place of the object?

I should probably do it like this:

```
let orientation: simd_quatf = anchor.orientation(relativeTo: self.box)

self.box.setOrientation(orientation , relativeTo: anchor)
```

But it doesn't work for me. Please help me.

Comment: were you able to solve it? how far did u got?

Comment: @Dariusz I was able to do it with the Scene kit. I couldn't do it with the Reality kit.